How to simulate match face ID / touch ID on XCUITest
How can I test biometric on UI Tests in Swift / iOS 18? This code not working.
+ (void)successfulAuthentication {
    notify_post("com.apple.BiometricKit_Sim.fingerTouch.match");
    notify_post("com.apple.BiometricKit_Sim.pearl.match");
}

+ (void)unsuccessfulAuthentication {
    notify_post("com.apple.BiometricKit_Sim.fingerTouch.nomatch");
    notify_post("com.apple.BiometricKit_Sim.pearl.nomatch");
}

